# Add css prefix to avoid potential class conflicts

Tags: html, css

How do I add a custom "prefix" to the i tag so that this i tag is not applied to all elements in the html?

My CSS:

```
i {
    color: red;
}
```

My HTML contains:

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i>
```

The red color must only be applied to that html fragment.

This is possibly a duplicate but I wasn't able to find the information I need.

Comment: You would add a unique class or ID to the element and use it as the selector. `.myUniqueClass { color: red; }`. Read [Getting started with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/Getting_started#Adding_a_class)

Comment: like this?
.myclass i {
    color: red;
}

<i class="myclass fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i>

Comment: It would be `i.myclass { ... }` instead of `.myclass i { ... }`. You could omit the `i` entirely if the class name is not used elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a single `i` that you want to refrence, you can use an `id`:

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x" id="mytag"></i>

<!--CSS->

#mytag or i#mytag for more specificity {
    //styles 
}
```

or add a new `class` to your `i` (separated by a space):

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x myclass"></i>

<!--CSS->

.myclass or i.myclass for more specificity {
    //styles
}
```